# datetime vs bigint

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have several tables that must be joined based on start and stop dates, for instance ...

```
SELECT    * 
FROM      [t1] 
JOIN      [t2] 
   ON [t2].[start] BETWEEN [t1].[start] AND [t1].[stop] 
   OR [t2].[stop]  BETWEEN [t1].[start] AND [t1].[stop]
   OR [t2].[start] < [t1].[start] and [t2].[stop] > [t1].[stop]
```

These tables could be in the multiple-millions of rows.

I have the option to store the start/stop as datetime2 and/or bigint(nanoseconds since epoch). Given this option - would there be a performance gain by using the bigint if indexed?

Any pros/cons with either approach?

I would expect the integer approach to be faster -

Comment: Do you really need till nanosecond resolution or is seconds enough for you?

Comment: Unless the query runs in nanoseconds you will miss the nanosecond so I agree with erich007 as well do you need this resolution?

Comment: I do need sub-second resolution. The database as is uses datetimeoffset(7) values for the start/stop values. So - what I did was just go with the resolution (100 ns) that was native to the datetimeoffset(7) type (attempting to get the same resolution as the current source - while hopefully gaining performance from using the bigint)

Comment: Not answering your question but a comment on the condition. It is equivalent to the simpler: `ON [t2].[start] <= [t1].[stop] AND [t2].[start] <= [t1].[stop]`

Comment: I think bigint approach would work much much faster...

Comment: Here is a nice discussion maybe it can help you: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/25761/sql-server-2008-datetime-index-performance-bug

Comment: erich007 - That was my thought - just trying to justify it in my mind.

Comment: Correction, I meant: `[t2].[start] <= [t1].[stop] AND [t1].[start] <= [t2].[stop]`

Comment: Is this the *only* usage scenario you need to accommodate? If not, you really ought to be considering other scenarios also. Will you ever have to do any date based processing on these datetime values? Most of the time, the answer is yes. It's far better to store the values in the most appropriate general representation (`datetime2`) than to optimize for one narrow scenario. The `datetime2` type is already quite well optimized anyway, and can be indexed as easily as `bigint`.

Comment: It is possible that I have a bit of 'tunnel vision'. If there is no compelling reason to do the integer storage then maybe it is a non-issue. I just wanted to raise the integer idea and see if there might be performance gains to be had.

Comment: Create and indexed View from that query, that'll speed things up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `datetime2`.  In addition to "easier to read by human", easier to *program by a human*.  If you don't use a date type to represent a date, you'll have problems computing intervals, joining to other tables, comparing to external times e.g. `getdate()`.

As far as efficiency goes, for purposes of comparison the server almost certainly treats all date types as integers.  The only speed advantage that might be open to you, depending on whether you usually care about the seconds, would be clustering on `smalldatetime`, because it's 4 bytes.  You could still keep the high-resolution part as a separate `real`.

Answer (score 1):

As long as you use `datetime2` type probably there would be no difference, because both types are similar at size (`datetime2` -- 6 to 8 bytes, `bigint` -- 8 bytes).

I assume IO cost will be the only bottle neck, so it depends on how many records you compare (records to read) and how indexes will store `datetime2` type.

I would test & compare both options in your case and choose the better one keeping in mind that `datetime` is easier to read by human.